Which smart pointer to insert into linked list to maintain polymorphism?
I'm writing a simple compiler and I have a base class:
class Instruction
{
  public:  
    virtual std::string get_name() const = 0;
};

I create an instruction such as Compute:
class Compute
: public Instruction
{
  public:  
    std::string get_name() const override
    { return "Compute"; }
};

I want to create a container, say std::list, of pointers to instructions using smart pointers.
One feature is to iterate through the container, calling the virtual function get_name() on all the instructions, let's say for printing all the instruction names.  (Another idea would be to call an execute or validate function on all the instructions).

What smart pointer should I use?
How is the pointer inserted into the std::list?
Does deferencing the pointer still invoke polymorphism?

Note:  The internet search for "c++ smart pointer linked list" turns up answers about using a smart pointer to link nodes together.  I'm talking about using smart pointers as the data in a node.
Note:  The examples of "What is a smart pointer and when should I use one" do not cover the case of polymorphism and the smart pointer inserted into the container.
The lifetime of the target object (the object being point to) is the life of the container or the program.

If you have a pointer to the base-class, pointing to an actual child-class object, then it doesn't really matter which smart pointer to use, all pointers will work just fine. What you should think about is ownership... Who owns the object? Are object in the container owned by the container and only the container? Or is the ownership shared between different entities? If you can only one single owner at a time, then use std::unique_ptr<Instruction>, otherwise std::shared_ptr<Instruction>.

As an addendum to my previous comment, you don't have to use smart pointers if there's no ownership semantics involved. You can just use plain normal "raw" pointers. What you should not do is to treat smart pointers as some kind of automatic garbage collecting, auto-deleting thing.

If you need your compiler to perform then prefer containers of std::variant<all, possible,instructions>, classes from boost::poly_collection or boost::intrusive or something like that. The smart pointers cause noticeable overhead because of piles of dynamic allocations and damaged memory locality for each tiny parsed element.

Add a virtual destructor to Instruction and use a unique_ptr.
Insert using make unique, or moving a uniqie ptr, or emplacing a raw pointer.  Lots of ways.
If your instruction objects are immutable (completely const after creation) consider a shared ptr - use of shared ptr in other circumstances to "solve lifetime issues" is ill-advised, as it hides issues instead of solving them in my experience.
Note that std::list should only be used when inserts/deletes in the middle of the list happen far more often than traversals do (including traversals to find or insert something), or absolute object address stability is needed.  This is an extremely rare requirement: the short form is don't use std list.
